# Include javascript in Typo3 raw HTML content

Tags: javascript, typo3

In a Typo3 *raw HTML content* container, any `<script>` tag containing JavaScript seems to be filtered out, not being executed.

Is this standard behaviour, or is it most likely being done by some plugin? If this is standard behaviour, how could I deactivate it for a specific page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better way to add javascript  in footer part, by adding footer  part or by using page.includeJSFooter.

As per my suggestion you should only include typoscript in which page where plugin added.

Comment: Another way is to include the script everywhere, but build it in a way that it does nothing if not on the correct page. That would result in fewer TypoScript templates, which I think is a good idea.